# How to catch all and only button release events in Qt?

Tags: qt, event-handling, mouseevent

My team is developing an UI for an apparatus with touch screen and we would like it to emit a sound (from a buzzer) each time the user correctly presses a button (so using the release event). Notice that I don't want to play the sound after each click on the interface, but *only* when the click is over a button.

We use many types of button, sometimes QPushButton and most of the times customized buttons derived from QAbstractButton. In most cases these buttons get an `objectName`.

So I supposed in order to do that, I would have to catch the `MouseButtonRelease` event and since I'm already working with a subclass of QApplication to handle excetions, I decided to do this in the `notify` function.

I tried, then, some methods to recognized when the MouseButtonRelease was related to a button but none of them were successfull. The best one, verifying the receiver's `objectName` was still not good enought not only because not all buttons had an `objectName` (which, of course, can be handled), but specially because not always the event was caught for buttons *with* names set. In other words, sometimes I would click in a button and it recognizes the event and sometimes I would click in the *same* button and the event is not recognized.

I did some research and another method I found was to set an event filter in the MainWindow, but not all widgets have the MainWindow as their parent which means I would have to Ctrl+c / Ctrl+V the same code time after time when I obviously want something more localized (i.e. in only one spot).

So why it happens that the `notify` not always handles the events? And how could I do this? Any suggestions are appreciated specially one that is less heavier then handling the events globally.

As info, the other two ways I tried to catch the events with similar or even worst results inside `notify` were with `receiver->inherits("...")` and `qobject_cast< QAbstractButton* >(receiver)`.

Comment: You should debug **why** a click in the same button was not recognized. In general, override `notify` is a not-so-good way in the sense that only *one* QApplication subclass can be created, so it centralizes all such event filtering (what if tomorrow you want also catch all tablet-pan events...). Consider installing an event filter on the QApplication object instead.

Comment: @peppe your "install event filter" solution worked! The only problem is that now more then one warning is emitted for only one button pressed. :P